# How to make Apache Tika work with InputStream or File just like a byte array?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, apache-tika

I have this code that detect a file correctly as UTF-8

```
byte[] data = getFileContent(file)
CharsetDetector charsetDetector = new CharsetDetector()
charsetDetector.setText(data)
CharsetMatch[] charsets = charsetDetector.detectAll()
```

charsets[0] returns UTF-8

I want to do this in a way that large files don't overflow the memory

```
InputStream inputStream = getInputStreamOfFile(file)
CharsetDetector charsetDetector = new CharsetDetector()
TikaInputStream tikaInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(inputStream)
charsetDetector.setText(tikaInputStream)
CharsetMatch[] charsets = charsetDetector.detectAll()
```

But charsets[0] returns ISO-8859-2 to the same file as UTF-8

Comment: I tried TikaInputStream.get(file) but still return ISO-8859-2

Comment: In the version 1.0 returns ISO-8859-2 in 1.22 returns ISO-8859-1

Comment: Apparently the difference is that with bytes, it will analyze all the bytes and take its decision, while with streams or files it will read until it is satisfied enough to provide an answer. I suppose you could try to load "a big chunk of the file, more than what it would read by default" in a byte array and have it analyze that. If you want the exact same results though, you need to do the exact same thing, and load the entire file in memory. Generally speaking, don't autodetect charsets, tell the computer what is the charset. And don't have anything but utf-8. You don't need these problems.